# ¿como generar un csv de usuarios en Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Tengo un problema al intentar generar un archivo CSV con todos los usuarios registrados para exportarlo.

```
def descargar_usuarios(request):
perfiles = Perfil.objects.all()
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/csv')
with open('usuarios.csv','wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    columnas = []
    writer.writerows(['usuario','nombre','apellido','correo','boutique'])
    for p in perfiles:
        columnas = [p.usuario.username,p.usuario.first_name,p.usuario.last_name,p.usuario.email,p.boutique]
        writer.writerows(columnas)
    writer.save(response)
    return response
```

Intento escribir todas las columnas de una sola vez pero no encuentro la manera.

Una vez lo tenga no quiero guardarlo en el servidor, sino descargarlo desde el navegador.

Comment: Tal como tienes montado el bucle, usa `writerow()` en lugar de `writerows()`. Si en vez de volcar a un fichero lo haces a una cadena, después podrías retornar esa cadena como respuesta. Para ello puedes usar la clase `io.StringIO`

Comment: pero estoy usando python 3.5 y io es de 2.7 si no recuerdo mal

Comment: No, lo que era de python 2.7 era el módulo `stringio`. En python 3 su funcionalidad sigue existiendo, pero está ahora en el módulo `io`, en su clase [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

para descargar un csv no solo hay que especificar el content_type , sino que tambien la cabecera.

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'
```

con esto te lo descargará en el navegador

puedes ver más detalles en la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/outputting-csv/) oficial

Comment: es lo que necesitaba, gracias.

Comment: genial, me alegro de ayudar